# How to configure an application with a guava dependency and Espresso

Tags: gradle, guava, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I have guava as an application dependency and using Espresso in the Instrumentation tests.
Since Espresso comes with `com.google.guava:guava:16.0`, and I have `guava` in the application dependency, I have to handle a duplicated dependency issue.

Jake Wharton noted in [Double Espresso](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) that I can resolve a duplicated dependency issue by doing something like:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3') {
  exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'
  exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

with that line though, I am getting bunch of the following errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Optional.get
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.ThreadPoolExecutorExtractor.getAsyncTaskThreadPool(ThreadPoolExecutorExtractor.java:50)
```

which seems like Espresso is not finding the guava dependency.
When I try with

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
androidTestCompile ('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r2') {
  exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger'
  exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
androidTestCompile('com.google.guava:guava:17.0')
```

Now that `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Optional.get` is gone from the espresso code, but I am still getting the following error when an Instrumentation test hits the application code which use one of guava's methods: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

This error occurs when I get rid of `androidTestCompile('com.google.guava:guava:17.0')` as well.

I tried with `AndroidTestProvided` with guava, no luck.

And I am running out of ideas to why it can't find guava's path when instrumentation tests hit application code with guava methods.

here is a stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/themis/clioAndroid/activity/calendar/calendarEntry/CalendarEntryListAdapter$1
at com.themis.clioAndroid.activity.calendar.calendarEntry.CalendarEntryListAdapter.<clinit>(CalendarEntryListAdapter.java:112)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:315)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:58)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
... 35 more
```

where it hits `new Ordering<SomeClass>()` which uses `com.google.common.collect.Ordering`.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: @yogurtearl I just pasted the stack trace. please let me know if you need other information.

Comment: are you using proguard? If so, does the NoSuchMethodError go away if you disable proguard?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Proguard being a pain.

Proguard or the way the Android gradle plugin is set up does not lead to very intelligent about handeling the espresso libraries. Add

```
-keep class com.google.common.** { *; }
```

to your `proguard-rules.txt`

Or if you're using proguard to get around the 65K method limit consider switching to the [MultiDex support package](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).